# Reactjs: How to improve performance of long table with bootstrap style?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, html-table

When I am displaying lots of data, say 10000 rows, with a bootstrap style table generated with reactjs, the page halted for several seconds. It looks pretty slow. It's just simple table with 1 column. I remembered that when I am having 300 rows with 5 columns, the page will be very slow and the browser will stuck.

I used to use extjs, it's pretty fast even with 100000 items.

I am wondering if there is any way to improve the performance of bootstrap tables generated with react js?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you display rows in ExtJS & ReactJS? Because it really matters to performance when dealing with massive amount of DOMs. In general, intuitively manipulate DOMs is much slower in ReactJS if your DOM tree is huge, so there are several ways to optimize it. For example, [Fixed Data Table](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/) is an optimization for handling huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

client side wont help you much if you must have all the 100000 rows in the html file.
Is it possible to divide the list to pages? or load a shorter lists in reaction to the user behavior like filter text, scroll, click "see more", etc.

Comment: Since extjs can handle thousands of rows at the same time, so I think it's possible for html to handle such number of records in the browser. However I  don't know the myth behind extjs, so I am wondering if there is anyway to do it.

Comment: ExtJS uses a very complex logic to create a BufferedRenderer that will render/de-render rows as you scroll the grid. One thing you could to is use the extjs-react project to use Ext Grid and enjoy the benefits of the BufferedRenderer